# Mongoose + NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have in my mongoDB more than 50000 entries with an ID (in one collection).

I would like to get only the ID (and not the other infos).

In **server.js**, I connect to mongoDB via mongoose:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://10.3.5.12/mydb');
```

I need to iterate all the 50 000 entries to check the ID, check the duplicates and store in a list.

Do I need to create a controller? It will be very heavy with 50 000 entries?
Any idea how I can proceed?

```
var listId= [];
...
listId.push(id);
```

[EDIT] Could I try something like that with mongoose?

```
    MyModel.find().distinct('id', function(error, id) {
        // ids is an array of all ObjectIds
       var listId= [];
       ...
       listId.push(id);
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "check the double one"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean duplicates.

Comment: So you're basically trying to get all id's in the database, removing all  duplicates?

Comment: check mapreduce : http://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/mongodb-how-to-check-for-duplicates-in-a-collection/

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes. Then I have a list with unique ID and I can use it later with AngularJS.

Comment: @Jose Have you checked mapReduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Mongoose 3.x+ you can do this:

```
MyModel.find().distinct('_id', function(error, ids) {
    // ids is an array of all ObjectIds
});
```